# Using PredicateBuilder in Projections with child collections

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, predicatebuilder

I'm using PredicateBuilder ( From LinqKit).

This is my code :

```
Dim mylist as IQueryable(of MyObj1)
Dim pred1 = PredicateBuilder.True(Of Myobj1)()
Dim pred2 = PredicateBuilder.True(Of ch1)()
Dim pred3 = PredicateBuilder.True(Of ch2)()
pred1=pred1.And(Function(t) t.id=5)
pred2=pred2.And(Function(t1) t1.vl1>=7)
pred3=pred3.And(Function(t2) t2.quantity<=4)
mylist = (From t In context.Myobj1s.Where(pred1)Select New With { _
     .Parent = t, _
    .child1 = t.ch1s.AsQueryable.Where(pred2), _
.child2 = t.ch2s.Asqueryable.Where(pred3) _
 }).ToList
```

But I'm getting this error :

```
The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

I try also to use AsExpandable instead of AsQueryable, but the problem is not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [alternative to Linqkit's PredicateBuilder](http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/) that doesn't use `Expression.Invoke`. This makes it far more suitable for predicates that are to be translated by a SQL provider.

If you use this predicate builder you can use your code without any changes.

Comment: Thank you , but please how can I use this method ? I mean is there a package on nugget that I should install ,  what should I include...etc ? ,

Comment: No, there isn't, sadly. You'll have to convert the source to VB code (and add it to your code base), or compile it as a C# class library and add it as a reference.

Comment: Does this also work with ordinary Linq collections, or only those using SQL providers?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't know what exactly you mean by "ordinary Linq collections", but there's no magic involved here. The builder just builds `Expression`s and you can use these anywhere where expressions apply. If you mean linq-to-objects, of course you know that the expressions should be compiled. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I think so, thanks.  So this PredicateBuilder has a wider range; i.e. a larger set of more general cases under which it can be used.

Comment: @Gert Arnold : sorry , I don't know C# , but I put this code in new C# dll project , I generate the dll file , after I add a reference to this file on my project , I add the Imports  UnivBuilder , but I get error on this line

Comment: @Alex:  You should probably spend some time trying to figure some of this out yourself.  Gert has pointed you in a good direction, and as I pointed out in your previous question, we don't provide extended help or consultations here.  We're just a question and answer site, and not particularly well suited to "learning programming, one question at a time" or "building applications, one question at a time."

Comment: @Robert : Yes , but if I can't include this on my project I can't say that is a good direction or doesn't work at all.Remember that I spent so much time in the previous question trying to use  your suggestions and at the end  I not resolved my problem. I'm asking for the library because I don't know c#

Comment: Pasting code into a library, compiling that library and then referencing it in your project are all considered *essential skills.*  You're expected to already know how to do these things.

Comment: Thank you ! As I wrote before , I done all these but doesn't work

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.  If you want troubleshooting help getting the new library to work in your project, write a new question that explains all the steps you did and showing the code you used, and specify exactly what the problem is, including any error messages that you are getting.

Comment: @alex The problem is, we can't see what's wrong. You probably made some mistake, same as I always stumble when I try to write VB. A new question would be OK. This gem deserves more exposure anyway.

Comment: Sorry friends. Was my mistake.I was targeting the C# library to .net 4.5 and I forget that my application was for Net 4.0 After make the changes everything works.

Comment: @Gert : Your solutions is working only with Lazyloading=False , but if I set false Lazyloading , I need to use an include inside the predictions which seems to not working.Because ch1 has also a child collection ch11 that I need to load. Any solutions ?

Comment: @alex, I refer to Robert's previous comment. You can't keep asking new questions in comments. There's such a thing as site etiquette. Plus it's not as effective a asking a new question with ample problem description.

Comment: @Gert : Sorry , I start a new question